# Couchdb with JWT auth has error "unknown_error : undef" not able see Fauxton

Tags: couchdb, jwt

Here is the config local.ini file

```
[jwt_auth]
required_claims = sub

[jwt_keys]
hmac:_default = aGVsbG8=

[chttpd]
authentication_handlers = {couch_httpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}
```

When i try to access http://localhost:5984 i am getting the below error

```
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"undef","ref":6776463}
```

and i can see the below log in console

```
[error] 2020-09-20T14:37:04.994313Z nonode@nohost <0.506.0> 8bbcfe9007 req_err(6776463) unknown_error : undef
    [<<"chttpd_auth:jwt_authentication_handler/1">>,<<"chttpd:authenticate_request/2 L531">>,<<"chttpd:process_request/1 L303">>,<<"chttpd:handle_request_int/1 L243">>,<<"mochiweb_http:headers/6 L150">>,<<"proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 L247">>]
```

More info:

a: running on docker

b: couch version 3.0

Did i miss any configuration or do we have any refrence where i can cross check configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue with version couch db version

update to 3.1.1

```
[jwt_auth]
required_claims = exp

[jwt_keys]
hmac:_default = aGVsbG8=

[chttpd]
authentication_handlers = {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}
```

These are the configuration in .ini file